# Should my 110 volt outlet show 37 volts when breaker is off?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

When replacing a very old GFCI outlet, my first step was to disconnect the circuit at the breaker box. But when I measure the voltage at the outlet, I still see a reading of 37 volts AC. I expected to see 0 volts. What might be the cause of this?

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/126411/why-do-i-still-read-voltage-on-outlet-when-i-turn-off-breaker and possibly [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=ghost+voltage+outlet+breaker+off+site:diy.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Plug in a light/radio to check/make sure, but it is probably phantom voltage.  The wires are picking up induced voltage from another live cable close by/both cables lay close to each other for a short distance.